# Invalid Syntax - List index

Tags: python, list

im writing the code below:

```
def add_to_index(index,keyword,url):
    i=0
    while i<=len(index):
    if keyword in index[i]:
        index[i][1].append(url)
    else:
        index.append([keyword,[url]])
    i=i+2
```

Im curious because when I define the index as

```
index = []
```

gives me the error *list out of range*, whats makes sense because there is no entry in my list, but when I define the index as

```
 index=[['udacity',['http_qualquer'],['udacity',['http_any']]]
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_azqmlozsjr/main.py", line 18
    def add_to_index(index,keyword,url):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And there is no error in the syntax of this specific line, if the syntax was wrong the error should have appeared when the index was empty.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in your list literal

Comment: @Barmar Python Shell wouldn't let you go to the next prompt :)

Comment: Syntax errors are printed at the point where Python notices something has gone wrong, not necessarily at the point where you actually messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## use index this one

It should end with four brackets 
check that number of open brackets should match number of closed brackets

```
index=[['udacity',['http_qualquer'],['udacity',['http_any']]]]
```